# How many times are we going to answer the conflation and PPI question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-question

Lets not kid ourselves by saying we close duplicates. We in fact are not closing duplicates. Two of the more prominent questions regard the

- PPI/DPI on digital images meant for web use
- The conflation issue (typically white lines in between 2 shapes)

These questions pop up on a timely manner 1-3 times a month and quite often we do not in fact mark them as duplicates.

How exactly is it good for us to not mark them as duplicates?

Comment: We need a single canonical answer for the conflation issue; it comes up so often and there's already a few decent dupes but I can either never find them or just don't know which one to use... the resolution issue is, well, not as easy (as seen by your previous meta attempt) :)

Comment: And to answer your title question... many many times :(

Answer (score 7):

It isn't. We should mark these as duplicates, provided there is a good Q&A to refer the dupes to. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Also, if there is no good Q&A for this, we can make a canonical one that is intended to be the target question for duplicate closure.